# .snappy.parquet ファイルをパースしたい

Tags: macos

AWS のコスト分析をしようと、 AWS の Cost Explorer をいじっていって、 S3 に詳細データを出力するように指定したところ、 `cost-report-1.snappy.parquet` ファイルがS3 に保存されるようになりました。しかし、このファイルの読み込み方が分かりません。

## 質問

`.snappy.parquet` ファイルの中身をひとまず確認したいと思っています。どうやったらこのファイルはパースできますでしょうか?

MacOS を利用しており、スクリプトの系言語や、シェルコマンドでパーサーを実行するなど、シェルからの操作がやりやすい形式であって、中身を読み込めればひとまず何でも良いと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

".snappy.parquet" でweb検索すると以下の記事中で [parquet-tools](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools) というツールが紹介されていました。

[parquet-toolsでApache Parquet形式のファイルをローカルでお手軽に確認する](https://engineering.mobalab.net/2020/02/21/check-parquet-on-local-using-parquet-tools/)

> Javaでできているようで、使用するには自前でコンパイルするか、macOSのユーザーであればHomebrewでインストールが可能です。僕はHomebrewを使いました:
>
> ```
> brew install parquet-tools
> ```

いくつかのサブコマンドが用意されており、一緒に "Parquet" ファイルを引数に指定すればよいそうです。
`cat` で中身を見る場合は以下の通り。

> ```
> $ parquet-tools cat ~/Downloads/part-00000-xyz.snappy.parquet
>
> user_id = 1
> name = Jiro Yamada
> birthdate = 1990-01-12
> gender = 1
> ```